# Assign coordinate information from a georeferenced TIFF to a CSV file of exactly the same area

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

Say I have a GeoTIFF that covers an area of 2000mx1000m. The GeoTIFF is 2000x1000 pixels. It has been exported from QGIS.

In another software package (with no georeferencing) I import this GeoTIFF as a ground plane; it is scaled correctly in meters.

I add some points over the top & I export these as a CSV file, units are meters.

Essentially, this CSV file is using a local grid.

Can I somehow assign the same coordinate system to this CSV? In my mind, I'm happy to treat the TIFF and CSV as if they are flat.

I have been using the Geoscience "create local CRS" but it would be easier if I can copy some metadata or similar and avoid the clunky workflow.

Comment: Import the csv to QGIS and when creating points use the CRS you used for exporting the geo tiff. For any further advice, it would be good to have more information like a csv file with sample data and information about the initial CRS of the Geo Tiff.

Comment: I'm using software that doesn't have any georeferencing capability. I have a script that exports my cameras (as points) to a CSV file, including their coordinates & orientation relative to the local grid (scene origin), along with various camera metadata. I have been aligning this in QGIS using the local grid tool. My thinking is that it would be 'simpler' to bring the Geotiff into my software, and then edit my script to export to the CSV file relative to the Geotiff. And then 'simply' assign the same coordinate system to the CSV file so I can drag/drop it into QGIS.